# Get the text from label of Radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple of radio button below. I want to get the text from the radio button I have chosen. For example: House Espresso or Guest Espresso. I have tried to use getElementsByName and for loop to get the checked value but it seems to return nothing.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="type">
                        <p>Type<p>
                        <input type="radio" id="houseEspresso" name="singleEspresso" checked="checked"onclick="addProduct(this)">
                        <label for="houseEspresso">House Espresso</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="guestEspresso" name="singleEspresso" onclick="addProduct(this)">
                        <label for="guestEspresso">Guest Espresso</label><br> 
                    </div>
```

And here is my Javascript code:

```
var type = document.getElementsByName("singleEspresso")
    for (var i=0; i<type.length; i++){
        if(type[i].checked){ 
            var title_type=type[i].innerText
            console.log(title_type)
        }
    }
```

Can anyone give me an idea to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: what text exactly? text wrapped by `label` element? when do you want to access the text, on radio change event?

Comment: why not give the `label` elements a class or unique id and then retrieve the text with `getElementsByName`

Comment: `let selectedRadio = 'House Espresso';
function addProduct() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.type input').forEach(input => {
    if(input.checked) {
      selectedRadio = input.nextElementSibling.innerHTML
    }
  });
}`

Comment: @hussain.codes yeahhh that's right. For exp i chose the second button. I want it to display the text "Guest Espresso"

Comment: Is this Javascript code you shared the implementation of click event listener for the radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to get `innerText` from the `<input>`, which has none. You need to get the `<label>`'s text:

```
for (var i=0; i<type.length; i++){
      if(type[i].checked){ 
            var title_type=type[i].nextElementSibling.innerText
            console.log(title_type)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a checked input, for that you can use `:checked` css selector. Then you can pick any value from input DOM element which ties it to label (in your case it's `id`). And basing on the id you can find corresponding label.

```js
  const selectedRadioInput = document.querySelector('[name=singleEspresso]:checked');
  const inputId = selectedRadioInput.id;
  const label = document.querySelector(`[for=${inputId}]`);
  console.log(label.innerText);
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yo18mx9k/2/

Comment: getting error ```"<a class='gotoLine' href='#38:89'>38:89</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: addProduct is not defined"
```

Comment: Just ignore the error, it is caused by their `onclick="addProduct(this)"`, which is unrelated to the question. I've updated the demo removing this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a value to input radio: `<input type="radio" value="1">`
Then just get the buttons and see which one is checked, like this:

```
let house = document.getElementById('houseEspresso');
let guest = document.getElementById('guestEspresso');
if (house.checked) {
  console.log(house.value);
} else if (guest.checked) {
  console.log(guest.value);
}
```

However, I would recommend that you take a look at [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) so you can make it easier:

```
$("input[name='singleEspresso']:checked").val();
```

Comment: I forgot about the value attribute :facepalm:

Comment: that's like using hacks what if he added more radio buttons in the future.

Comment: @AmAnKumAr That's not an hack. Using the value attribute of input is a spec

Comment: It's hack only, what if he had to add 200 more radio buttons in the future, do you want him to write 200 variables?

Comment: @AmAnKumAr that's why I recommended taking a look at jQuery, is much more simple and prevent future changes

Comment: Oh, your comment is about the variables for each input element. They can get the elements by class name or some other shared selector. However I don't even think he needs to declare variables if this is a click event listener.